# error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Form1' could not be found

Tags: nant

Currently I am developing a NAnt script to build a Windows forms application. After build the NAnt script, I am getting the error as

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Form1' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? )
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\NAnt\examples\SampleWindowsApplication\Sample.Build(24,10):
>   External Program Failed:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe (return code was 1)”

Can anyone please advise to resolve this issue?

Please find my code below.

```nant
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="SampleWindowsApplication" default="run">
<property name="basename" value="SampleWindowsApplication"/>
<property name="debug" value="true"/>   

<target name="clean">
    <delete>
        <fileset>
            <include name="bin/${basename}-??.exe"/>                
        </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>

<target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="bin" />
    <assemblyfileset id="Sample.assemblies">
            <include name="C:\Program Files\NAnt\examples\SampleWindowsApplication\SampleWindowsApplication\Assemblies\Sam.Grid.Base.dll" />
            <include name="C:\Program Files\NAnt\examples\SampleWindowsApplication\SampleWindowsApplication\Assemblies\Sam.Grid.Windows.dll" />
            <include name="C:\Program Files\NAnt\examples\SampleWindowsApplication\SampleWindowsApplication\Assemblies\Sam.Shared.Base.dll" />
            <include name="C:\Program Files\NAnt\examples\SampleWindowsApplication\SampleWindowsApplication\Assemblies\Sam.Shared.Windows.dll" />
            <!--<include name="C:\Program Files\NAnt\examples\SampleWindowsApplication\SampleWindowsApplication\Assemblies\System.Windows.Forms.dll" />-->
    </assemblyfileset>
    <csc target="exe" output="bin/${basename}.exe" debug="${debug}" >           

        <references refid="Sample.assemblies" />
        <resources>
            <include name="C:\Program Files\NAnt\examples\SampleWindowsApplication\SampleWindowsApplication\licenses.licx"/>
        </resources>
        <sources>
            <include name="C:\Program Files\NAnt\examples\SampleWindowsApplication\SampleWindowsApplication\Program.cs"/>
        </sources>
    </csc>        
</target>

<target name="run" depends="build">
    <exec program="bin/${basename}-cs.exe" basedir="."/>        
</target>
</project>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I'll just add the obvious comment that it seems your actual `Form1` class does not seem to be included in the build. Hard to say more than that without seeing the relevant section of the build file.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks for your comment.Please find my code now.I have attached it.

Comment: You should probably add your `Form1.cs` and `Form1.Designer.cs` (or whatever relevant names) to the `sources` section along with `Program.cs`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thank you. i will check now..

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson currently am encountered in to an license issue.. eventhough i added an license.licx file. i have checked with reflector tool also. My license is embedded with that exe. But am getting license error..

Comment: You may want to start a new question for that since it's unrelated to your original problem.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson i have created the new question.. Please refer the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167844/license-error-occur-while-compile-the-nant-script

Answer (score 0):

This is typically cause when you add a new file to your solution but don't commit them.
Check to make sure that Form1.cs and Form1.Designer.cs have been added to your source control repository. It looks like your project file was added and committed correctly but some source control tools require you to manually add new files before committing them.